# Runtime error 438 on remove dynamically added userform control

Tags: vba, excel

I've got the following code:

```
Private Sub cboA_change()
    'Something to determine number of controls there should be, variable gC
    'Something to determine number of controls there are, variable nC

    'The first time the code runs, the following code runs:
    For i = nC to gC
        frmA.Frame1.Controls.Add("txtGroup" & i)
    Next


    'The second time the code runs, the following is executed:
    For i = 7 To nC
        Me.Frame1.Controls("txtGroup" & i).Remove 'ERROR HERE
    Next

    For i = nC to gC
        frmA.Frame1.Controls.Add("txtGroup" & i)
    Next
End Sub
```

Something like this, the code is way bigger and I tried to clear it up so if the structure doesn't seem right, that doesn't matter really.

I debugged the `Add` statement and I know there is a control added to the userform, called `txtGroup7`. However, when I later try to remove this control, I get `Run-time Error 438: Object Doesn't Support This Property or Method`. I tried changing the code to:

```
Me.Frame1.Controls.Remove ("txtGroup" & i)
```

But this didn't work either.

Can anybody point me in the right direction?

**Edit:**

I know the help says the following:

> "This method deletes any control that was added at run time. However,
>   attempting to delete a control that was added at design time will
>   result in an error."

But since the control is added in run-time (dynamically, with VBA code) this shouldn't be a problem, right?

**Edit 2:**

I don't get why this works, but it seems to work:

```
q=0
While q < Me.Frame1.Controls.Count
    If Me.Frame1.Controls(q).Name = "txtGroup7" Then
        Me.Frame1.Controls.Remove q
    Else
        q = q + 1
    End If
Wend
```

Comment: have you tried recompiling your project?  Sometimes excel gets a bit odd and a recompile fixes it.

Comment: If you have multiple controls named "txtGroup7", your code will delete all of them, while a call to `Remove` will only remove the first one.

Comment: By the way, I'm not sure you code from Edit2 is correct. isn't Count recalculed each loop? If so you might miss some controls.

Comment: You're right, I edited it in my code but forgot to edit it here. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You must have something else wrong in your code, because `Remove`should be working. Tried :

```
Private Sub ToggleButton1_Click()
    If ToggleButton1.Value = True Then
        Me.Frame1.Controls.Add "Forms.TextBox.1", "Text1", True
    Else
        Me.Frame1.Controls.Remove "Text1"
    End If
End Sub
```

on a UserForm with a ToggleButton and a Frame and it correctly add and remove the TextBox when pressed.

Comment: I really don't get what's wrong. I just found out that when I try looping through the element and remove it by index if the name corresponds, it does work.

Comment: Maybe you have multiple Controls with the same name? Names are not unique, so if you create two or more controls with the same name and call `Remove name`only once, it will looks like the control haven't been deleted.